# To find the best fit bucket in big query using mode or arrays or anything else

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, mode

I have a table in big query as follows:

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Person  |  Bucket1 |  Bucket2 |  Bucket3 |  Bucket4 |  Bucket5 |  Bucket6 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Person1 |        0 |        0 |      0.3 |      0.4 |        0 |      0.8 |
| Person2 |      0.2 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |      0.7 |
| Person3 |      0.3 |      0.1 |      0.4 |        0 |        0 |      0.5 |
| Person4 |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |      0.3 |      0.3 |
| Person5 |        0 |      0.8 |        0 |        0 |      0.9 |      0.8 |
| Person6 |        0 |      0.4 |      0.8 |        0 |        0 |      0.8 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I am trying to map each person to a bucket based on the value that is the highest. I do not want the bucket to be overloaded and trying to make sure the buckets are loaded evenly based on values.

So when Person 1 is mapped to bucket 6 (his highest value),
I want person2 to be mapped to bucket 1 (though bucket6 has the highest value, it was just mapped to person1)
Person 3 to bucket3 (logic as above and considering the second highest value)
Person 4 to bucket 5 (logic as above and considering the second highest value)
Person 5 to bucket 2 ( as  bucket 5 and bucket 6 were used  already once and bucket 2 was never used)
Person 6 to bucket 6 ( as bucket 2, 3 and 6 were all already used 1 once so mapping to the bucket with the highest value)

Expected Map Result: 2 columns with values as:

+---------+----------+
| Person  |  Bucket  |
+---------+----------+
| Person1 | Bucket6  |
| Person2 | Bucket1  |
| Person3 | Bucket3  |
| Person4 | Bucket5  |
| Person5 | Bucket2  |
| Person6 | Bucket6  |
+---------+----------+

Comment: Can you state what you have tried so far?

Comment: What is your desired result? Two columns?

Comment: Why not just round-robin the assignments?  Just ignore the buckets entirely.  Also, what happens on the 7th row in the table?

Comment: 1. I am able to think of solutions in Java or Python but not in SQL. In SQL all I could think of was assigning a column to each bucket that will have value 0 initially then increment by 1 each time the bucket is chosen. This way, lag function can be used to choose the bucket with the least value in previous row. Again complexity arose when I have to choose the nth highest value based on previous row. Sorted Array might help but not sure how to implement. 2. Yes my desired result is 2 columns. 3. I cannot do round robin assignments as I am mapping based on values

Comment: if you are `" ... able to think of solutions in Java or Python"` - explain us in plain English the logic  you want to apply in-scale  - not just with six items/buckets! it is hard (if possible at all) to generalize it to match whatever in your mind. I recommend you to update your question with more specifics

Comment: Can you share the query you have done until now, the results you've got and why its not your desired result?